# Replacing comma with dot and cast ElasticSearch painless

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have the following data in the elastic doc:

```json
"attributes": [
 {
   "id": "b538c008-5406-4e25-9236-eab62b0cc097",
   "value": "12,5",
   "attributeName": "Height",
   "attributeId": "08e85bc8-c30f-4621-9b66-f0eb785e2056"
 }
]
```

I need to transform the `string` into a `float`, but first I need to replace the comma with dot.

I have the following script for this:

```json
{
  "script": {
    "script": {
      "params": {
        "isFormatHeight": false,
        "isFormatLength": false,
        "max": 12.5,
        "min": 90
      },
      "source": "def value = doc['attributes.value'].value; def min = params.min; def max = params.max; if (value == 'No Format' || value == 'A Lot') { return true; } try { def floatValue = Float.parseFloat(value.replace(',', '.').trim()); return floatValue >= min && floatValue <= max; } catch (NumberFormatException e) { return false; }"
    }
  }
}
```

However, if you filter by `min: 12.5` the document is not returned, but it should, if you filter by `min: 12.4` the document is also returned. The error is in the casting.

My mapping:

```json
{
    "attributes": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "attributeName": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
            },
            "value": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "attributeId": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I tried this - https://gist.github.com/imotov/6f7f2c4818d2c9da6546165b6dab90e2

Comment: Don't you have min and max swapped in your script params? min should be 12.5 and max should be 90. Anyway, I get the same results as @imotov, i.e. the document is returned with 12.5